# ¿Cuándo se debe usar [es6]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

El wiki de [es6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) no incluye una orientación clara de uso, sólo "información enciclopédica". Por "información enciclopédica" me refiero a que se describe a que se refiere y que *es eso* a lo que se refiere, lo cual es una especificación de [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), la [ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html).

- ¿La orientación de uso debería indicar que se utilice para preguntas sobre la especificación en sí, sobre navegadores u otras cosas<sup>1</sup> que lo soportan?
- ¿Debería usarse "siempre" o "nunca" en conjunto con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)?

O por el contrario,

- ¿Debería ser un sinónimo de [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)?

<sup>1</sup>: Ejemplos de "otras cosas" mencionadas a para fines de clarificación sobre "otras cosas", sin implicar que soportan o no [es6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6): [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs), [electron](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron), [reac-native](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reac-native),[ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic), [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), [typescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)

Answer (score 2):

El estándar es ECMAScript, no?

Se llama "JavaScript" a los lenguajes que cumplen con el estándar ECMA, generalmente con la versión ECMAScript 5.1[<sup>a</sup>].

Es una etiqueta especializada que **debería** usarse con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (por cuestiones de visibilidad). Los ejemplos de la nota 1 de Ruben, también son especializaciones de [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Dado que la especificación del estándar ECMAScript será actualizada cada año[<sup>b</sup>], y habrá [es2017](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2017) y [es2018](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2018) tiene sentido usar etiquetas especializadas para preguntas relacionadas con los cambios identificados entre versiones.

> Por ejemplo, si una pregunta se refiere al método `String.prototype.padStart(maxLength, fillString=' ')`, una característica en [es2017](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2017)[<sup>c</sup>] **debería** tener las etiquetas `javascript` por lenguaje y `es2017` por especialización.

#### TL;DR

Mantener la etiqueta `javascript` como la identificación del lenguaje y `es6`, `es2017`, `es2018`  y subsecuentes como especialización. Propongo que la orientación de uso, emplee la conjugación **“debería”** en las etiquetas especializadas.

- [<sup>a</sup>]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
- [<sup>b</sup>]: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/
- [<sup>c</sup>]: http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_string-padding.html#_stringprototypepadstartmaxlength-fillstring-

Comment: Sí, el estándar es ECMAScript. Considerando que mencionas que cada año se actualiza y que para versiones futuras se use el año en lugar del número ordinal de versión, ¿no debería renombrar [tag:es6] a `es2015`? Por cierto, justo acabo de [responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67153/65) a una pregunta usando referencias a `es2016`

Comment: @Ruben: Deberían hacerse sinónimos. Creo que dejaría `es6` por familiaridad (y resultados en Google)  y `es2015` como un sinónimo, para las siguientes versiones, usar la etiqueta de la revisión del año que corresponda.